# Automated delete on SFTP server (PuTTY? WinSCP?)

Tags: sftp, putty, winscp

I'm searching for a solution to easily delete files on a SFTP server automatically after a specific period of days.

I read something about automation via PSFTP from PuTTY and WinSCP. But there are no examples for deleting files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With WinSCP, use the `rm` command with a filemask with a time constraint (to select only files with certain age, if I understand correctly, what you want to do).

E.g. to delete all files older than 5 days:

```
rm *<5D
```

For all the other instructions to assemble a script and schedule its run, see:

- [Automate file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP server or SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)
- [Schedule file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP/SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule)

See also:

- Documentation for the [`rm` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_rm);
- Documentation for the [file masks](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying this out :)

Answer (score -1):

SFTP server is also a SSH server. Write a simple code in any language that you're comfortable with and schedule it with crontab.

Comment: This is not always so. The user can have no shell access (SFTP access only)